# Word requests okay?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I wanted to ask:

> Is there a mathematical term for completing a collection of sets with the operations of intersection, union, and complement? In other words, all the regions of a Venn diagram of some sets.

Are such “word request” questions on-topic? By “word request,” I mean the OP has a mathematical object or result in mind, and wants to know if there’s an existing mathematical term for it.

Such questions are useful because once you know the name, you can Google it! Sometimes we genuinely don’t know if such an object even has a name. It can be really hard to find the right search results without one.

Comment: Have a look at Questions that are tagged [tag:terminology] to get a feel for what sort of context or prior research can make them acceptable.  It can be difficult to ask about things for which you don't know a "good name", so this sort of Question might be a first step to asking about a deeper problem.

Comment: c.f. my answer [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29622/12952)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, that's an admissible type of question. The relevant tag is [terminology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology).

Of course specific incarnations of such questions could have problems, e.g., they might be unclear or too vague. But, in principle, this type of questions is allowed.